# Phalcon PHP: getter/setter syntax for ->save()/->update()/->create()

Tags: php, getter-setter, phalcon

I'm a little bit confused after reading the documentation. It mentions that ->save()/->create()/->update() all will implicitly reference getters and setters for model properties if they exist. What's the syntax for this sort of thing? Specifically, what do I do when a property is related to a field in my table with underscores in it's name? An example of what I think should work:

```
class Events extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    protected $id;
    protected $event_name;

    public function setEventName($name){
        $this->event_name = $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: `class Events extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model` <- That violates Liskov Substitution Principle and Single-Responsibility Principle at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for telling me to google those I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not a direct answer:

For changing column names you can better use: [Column mapping](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#independent-column-mapping) then you would not worry about setters/getters.

Besides that AFAIK Phalcon uses magic getters/setters for fields, so if you have `$id` it will use magic getter for `$id` or use a `$eventsObj->getId()` if that method explicitly exist in class.